# How Memory Management Unit decide to map Pages into Pysycal memory frames?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, virtual-memory, mmu

In operating Systems their are chunks called pages of a process. So it will load only necessary pages into physical memory frames. My question is these processes in binary right? (instruction of process is in binary format at that stage?) Assume compiled c or c++ or any program. So page will contain part of that whole binary right? (please correct me if I wrong.) Do those pages contains binary parts form whole process? Then how memory management unit (MMU) will know which page to select next.. like that? because it don't know about process. Or its flow.. just binary?

Please Correct me if I made wrong. Here I have several questions that I have been struggling.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MMU doesn't do that. The operating system does that. The MMU only translates addresses whenever you access memory, in the way the operating system told it.